# Control higher derivatives of approximating sequence

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-methods, sobolev-spaces, approximation-theory

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^d$ be a bounded open set. Let $H_0^1(\Omega)$ be the usual Sobolev space.

From the definition it follows, that each $u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ can be approximated by a sequence $\{u_n\} \subset C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ (smooth and compactly supported functions).

Is it possible to somehow control the higher derivatives of the approximating sequence? Of course, we must have $\|u_n\|_{H^2(\Omega)} \to \infty$ if $u \not\in H^2(\Omega)$. But is it, e.g., possible to obtain a sequence $\{u_n\} \subset H^2(\Omega) \cap H_0^1(\Omega)$ with
$$\|u - u_n\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \le \frac{C}n \quad\text{and}\quad \|u_n\|_{H^2(\Omega)} \le C \, n\quad?$$

One possibility would be to extend $u$ by zero and use a mollification argument. This should yield a sequence $\{u_n\}\subset H^2(\Omega)$ satisfying the above properties. However, I do not see a reason how to construct the approximating sequence in $H_0^1(\Omega)$.

Comment: You want to write $u=v+w$ with some control on $\|v\|_{L^2}$ and $\|w\|_{H^2}$. This is morally equivalent to embedding $H^1$  in a real interpolation space between $L^2$ and $H^2$ (cf. [J-functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_space#J-method)), which should work for some [ranges of exponents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_space#Interpolation_of_Sobolev_and_Besov_spaces) but I don't have the energy to figure them out.

Comment: If you didn't have boundary conditions, then $v$ and $w$ would be obtained by partitioning the Fourier transform of $u$ by some sphere $\|\xi\| = R$. I think that explicitly working this out for $|\hat u(\xi)| \sim \|\xi\|^\alpha$ should indicate what growth of $H^2$ norm is required; it may depend on dimension $d$.